# How to turn the Frame in this code into a Panel inside of the Frame? WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

This is my code. It displays an image, and you can drag and drop and image from your desktop and it will replace the image. Works like I want. But I want to make a GUI and have this inside of it. I tried changing the Frame to a Panel and then putting that inside a Frame but I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone help me? I want to put some text/buttons above the image. Thanks!

```
import wx
from wx import *
import wx.lib.statbmp as SB
from PIL import Image
from pubsub import pub


PhotoMaxSize = 485


class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.widget = widget
        
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath=filenames[0])
        return True
        

class PhotoCtrl(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Photo Ctrl')
        
        bg3 = wx.Image('bg3.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        #img = wx.Image(485, 272.813)
        img = wx.Image(bg3)
        self.image_ctrl = SB.GenStaticBitmap(
            self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))
        file_drop_target = DropTarget(self)
        self.image_ctrl.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.image_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)
        
        pub.subscribe(self.update_image_on_dnd, 'dnd')
        
        self.Show()
        
    def update_image_on_dnd(self, filepath):
        self.on_view(filepath=filepath)
        
    def on_view(self, filepath):
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        
        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        
        if W > H:
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize * W / H
            
            
        img = img.Scale(new_w, new_h)
        self.image_ctrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()
        
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Edit the question to show what you tried and explain what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The panel should be a class of its own. I've created the class and moved the relevant code there (not tested so I'm not sure all of the code functions as you want)

```
import wx
from wx import *
import wx.lib.statbmp as SB
from PIL import Image
from pubsub import pub


PhotoMaxSize = 485


class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.widget = widget

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath=filenames[0])
        return True


class PhotoCtrl(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Photo Ctrl')

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)

        pub.subscribe(self.update_image_on_dnd, 'dnd')

        self.Show()

    def update_image_on_dnd(self, filepath):
        self.on_view(filepath=filepath)

    def on_view(self, filepath):
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()

        if W > H:
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize * W / H


        img = img.Scale(new_w, new_h)
        self.image_ctrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        bg3 = wx.Image('bg3.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        img = wx.Image(bg3)
        self.image_ctrl = SB.GenStaticBitmap(
            self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))
        file_drop_target = DropTarget(self)
        self.image_ctrl.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.image_ctrl)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks! It opens just fine and looks fine, but when I drag/drop image into the window its now showing this error now https://prnt.sc/MvVnbYeOTjm2

Comment: That's because on line 54 "self" is the frame and not the panel - you need to refactor your functions to take account of the fact that the  img_ctrl has moved - I did warn that some functions might not work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You can always re-juggle @Psionman's answer to make `PhotoCtrl` just a Frame and move your code into the MainPanel class, it might be more inline with what you were thinking (or not).

```
import wx
from wx import *
import wx.lib.statbmp as SB
from PIL import Image
from pubsub import pub


PhotoMaxSize = 485


class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.widget = widget

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath=filenames[0])
        return True


class PhotoCtrl(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Photo Ctrl')

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent       
        bg3 = wx.Image('test.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img = wx.Image(bg3)
        self.image_ctrl = SB.GenStaticBitmap(
            self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))
        file_drop_target = DropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)
        pub.subscribe(self.update_image_on_dnd, 'dnd')
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.image_ctrl, 0, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def update_image_on_dnd(self, filepath):
        self.on_view(filepath=filepath)

    def on_view(self, filepath):
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()

        if W > H:
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize * W / H


        img = img.Scale(new_w, new_h)
        self.image_ctrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))

        self.Fit()
        self.parent.Fit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()
```