# How to add smaller panel on top of existing panel inside frame? - WXPYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Below I have an example of my code, you can drag and drop an image from your desktop into the window and it will change the image in the app. I want to only drag/drop images into the image, not the border around the image in the window.

In another words, you can drag/drop images anywhere in the window, but I only want you to be able to drag/drop images on top of the image.

```html
import wx
from wx import *
import wx.lib.statbmp as SB
from PIL import Image
from pubsub import pub
import wx.lib.inspection #inspection tool




#=======================================================================#
# DRAG/DROP
#=======================================================================#

PhotoMaxSize = 485

class DropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.widget = widget

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        pub.sendMessage('dnd', filepath=filenames[0])
        return True












#=======================================================================#
# FRAME
#=======================================================================#





class PhotoCtrl(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Learning GUI', size=(800,500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#1a1a1a')
        
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.Show()
        
        
        







#=======================================================================#
# DRAG/DROP IMAGE PANEL
#=======================================================================#        
        
        


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent         
        bg3 = wx.Image('bg3.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)       
        img = wx.Image(bg3)
        self.image_ctrl = SB.GenStaticBitmap(
            self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img))
        file_drop_target = DropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)
        pub.subscribe(self.update_image_on_dnd, 'dnd')
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(5)
        sizer.Add(self.image_ctrl, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 10)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def update_image_on_dnd(self, filepath):
        self.on_view(filepath=filepath)

    def on_view(self, filepath):
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        

        if W > H:
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            new_h = PhotoMaxSize
            new_w = PhotoMaxSize * W / H
            
 
        
        img = img.Scale(new_w, new_h)
        self.image_ctrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))

        #self.Fit() #removing this makes window size not change when dropping pic in
        self.parent.Fit()
        
        
       





       

        
        
        
        
        
        
        
#=======================================================================#
# END
#=======================================================================#           
        
        
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = PhotoCtrl()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show() #inspection tool
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Do not use this forum to answer assignment questions. The idea is, you learn my sorting it out yourself

Comment: Thanks, thats not my intent, just looking for a point in the right direction

Comment: Ask your teacher

Comment: I fail to see how the question title and the actual question match up. But, if you look back at you original post,(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696286/how-to-turn-the-frame-in-this-code-into-a-panel-inside-of-the-frame-wxpython) you had `self.image_ctrl.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)` which is what you are now asking for. You set just the `image_ctrl` to be the drop target and not the whole panel i.e. `self`